# Wrong color in UIImageView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, ios-simulator

It looks like UIImageView (or the underlying UIView is changing my colors. 
[image: Change of color]

iPad simulator is on the left side, and on the right side is the same view from IB.
I have same effect on UITableViewCell, and on other views in the application. What's the problem, and how to deal with it?
It looks on a real iPad just like on a simulator.

Comment: Are you taking these screenshots with a Mac screen? Try inspecting this with Digital Color Meter on a Mac screen (I know it's weird but RGB results defer on non-Mac screens)

Comment: Also make sure your images are RGB not CMYK.

Comment: I can post a screenshot captured from a mac screen, but the difference remains. Furthermore, as I mentioned in the question, it looks pretty close on a real iPad and in the simulator, but both different from IB.

Comment: As @Stavash mentioned, use Digital Color Meter and check RGB value for the color in simulator, whether its matching with the value you selected in IB or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found out (by looking at jpeg sources using Dropbox iPad app) that the problem actually goes deeper into that: [StackExchange post.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23936/photoshop-to-ipad-color-profile-woes)
That solved my question. It still looks differently in IB and on device, but it's now pretty close to what I get in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that it has something to do with this, though I'm not too sure what it does. You might wanna try playing around with it and see what you get.

[image: Generic RGB seems to be the default option.]

Answer (score 1):

You need not to care about how it appears in the IB. The actual appearance you can see is in Device only.
Even the simulator and the Device may give different appearance of the images.

Comment: That's not an answer, actually. The problem IS that it looks differently in IB and in simulator, and looks the same on simulator and on a real device.